# Delete Node with given id but unknown node id in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have a firebase data structure which looks like this:

```
|---groups
|       |---group1
|       |       |---membernames
|       |              |---xy_unknownid
|       |                  |---givenname: "userx"
|       |              |---tv_unknownid
|       |                  |---givenname: "usery"
```

Now I want to delete the node xy_unknownid. But I only know the "givenname": userx.

I tried to delete the node with:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference
.child("groups")
.child("group1")
.child("membernames")
.child("$member")
.child("userx")
.getParent()
.setValue(null);
```

but this won't work because "Invalid Firebase Database path: $member. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'"

So my question is, how can I delete the node: "xy_unknownid" only knowing: "userx".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and tell me if this works,

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("groups").child("group1").child("membernames").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:snapshot.getChildren())
      {
         if(dataSnapshot1.child("givenname").getValue().toString().equals("userx"))
         {
             dataSnapshot1.getRef().setValue(null);
             break;
         } 
      }

   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   }
});
```

Comment: I have the feeling this is almost it. It deleted the node "givenname: userx". Can I get the parent someway?

Comment: `Firebase parent = dataSnapshot1.child("givenname").getRef()` you get the parent this way.

Comment: It is not working. with     dataSnapshot1.child("givenname").getRef().setValue(null);  is deleting "givenname: userx"  the parent node is still there

Comment: `dataSnapshot1.getRef().setValue(null);`. This will delete the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 steps:

1. Get the xy_unknownid by using query:

   ```
   mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("groups").child("group1").child("membernames"). orderByChild("givenname").equalTo("user")
   ```
2. Once you get the response inside the callback you can have the key using

   ```
   dataSnapshot.getKey()
   ```

and with that key use `setValue(null)` or `removeValue()`